# Making a database with custom commands in python

Tags: python, database, class

I'm trying to make a simple, local database using Python where I can set values, get values, etc and I keep getting this error:

```
#Simple Database
#Functions include      Set[name][value]
#                       Get[name]
#                       Unset[name]
#                       Numequalto[value]
#                       End
#                       Begin, Rollback, Commit

varlist = []
ops = []
class item:
        def __init__(self,name,value):
                self.name = name
                self.value = value
class db:
    def __init__(self):
            self.varlist = []
            self.ops = []
    def Set(self,nm,val):
            changed = False                 #Bool for keeping track of update
            for item in varlist:    #run through current list
                    if item.name == nm:     #If the name is found
                            item.value = val #update the value
                            changed = True  #found it
                            break                   #exit if found
            if not changed:
                    newitem = item() #Create a new one and append it
                    newitem.name = nm
                    newitem.value = val
                    varlist.append(newitem)
    def Get(key):
            for item in varlist:
                    if item.name == key:
                            return item.value
                            break

    def Unset(key):
            for item in varlist:
                    if item.name == key:
                            item.value = -1
                            break

    def Numequalto(key):
            count = 0
            for item in varlist:
                    if item.value == key:
                            count+=1
            return count

def main():
    newdb = db()
    varlist=[]
    comm = "" #prime it
    while comm.lower() != "end":
        comm = input("Command: ")
        if comm.lower() == "begin":
            print("----SESSION START---")
            while comm.lower() != "end":
                    comm = input("Command: ")
                    part = []
                    for word in comm.split():
                            part.append(word.lower())
                    print(part)
                    if part[0].lower()=="set":
                            newdb.Set(part[1],part[2])
                            print(varlist)
                    elif part[0].lower()=="get":
                            gotten = Get(part[1])
                            print(gotten)
                    elif part[0].lower()=="unset":
                            Unset(part[1])
                    elif part[0].lower()=="numequalto":
                            numequal = Numequalto(part[1])
                            print(numequal)
            print("Finished")
        else:
            print("--ERROR: Must BEGIN--")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run this, and try to create a new item in my list using the command

```
set a 25
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Volumes/CON/LIFE/SimpleDatabase.py", line 81, in <module>
    main()
File "/Volumes/CON/LIFE/SimpleDatabase.py", line 65, in main
    newdb.Set(part[1],part[2])
File "/Volumes/CON/LIFE/SimpleDatabase.py", line 27, in Set
    newitem = item() #Create a new one and append it
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'item' referenced before assignment
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm pretty new to Python

Comment: The `item` class is shadowed by the `item` in the for-loop. You should use the CamelCase convention for your class names: name your class `Item` and your variable `item`.

Comment: Why are you rolling your own DB instead of using the aqlite3 module tha ships with Python?

Comment: please name your classes with a capital as the first letter, totally threw me off for a second

Comment: @JamesThieleHe's not trying to roll his own SQL database, but his own key-value database, so `sqlite3` would not be helpful. Of course `dbm` (or, for 2.x, `anydbm`) and/or `shelve` would do the trick. Or, for that matter, a plain old `dict`, since he's just trying to store his key-value database in memory…

Comment: @WaleedKhan Was right. Can't believe I missed/didn't think of something that easy.

Comment: reading pep8 should help your coding style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
for item in varlist:
```

shadows the class `item` with a local variable. So that when you get to your `item()` it thinks you are trying to call the local variable instead of the class.  You can tell that your class `item` is never being constructed because it would fail as you are passing no parameters to the `__init__`

Also you should really call your class `Item`.  Once I did that I got the constructor error as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues with your code:

1. You are shadowing the class `item` with a local variable of the same name.
2. You are using `varlist` instead of `self.varlist`.
3. Some of your class methods doesn't recieve a `self` first argument.
4. Also there is a strong convention in python to name classes with a first capital letter.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, why? All of these points are true, except maybe technically #3 (as long as the OP consistently ignores `self.varlist` and instead uses the global `varlist`, things will sort of work by accident).

Comment: That being said, this isn't an exhaustive list. From a quick glance, besides the blatant errors (e.g., `item` takes two arguments in its constructor, but instead he's trying to construct it with no arguments and then set the attributes after the fact), there are a whole lot of things that are just very confusing very bad ideas (e.g., having global, local-to-`main`, and instance-attribute-of-`db` variables with the same name, using globals as instance attributes, using classic classes…).

Comment: 2 is not necessarily a problem, it would use the global varlist, but its hard to tell if that is what he meant, since there are 3 different varlists in the program

Answer (score 1):

Not trying to be implite, just constructive here.  I'm concerned that while there are comments questioning the intent to implement your own dictionary, no answer stated this forcefully.  I say this only because part of Python (beyond the semantics, language, etc...) is the culture.  We speak of things being 'Pythonic' for a reason - part of the value of this language is the culture.  There are two aspects here to pay attention to - first, 'Batteries Included' and second, "Don't Reinvent the Wheel".  You're reimplimenting the most fundamental composite (oxymoron, I know) data type in Python.

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a['bob'] = 1
>>> a['frank'] = 2
>>> a
{'frank': 2, 'bob': 1}
>>> del a['frank']
>>> a
{'bob': 1}
>>> del a['bob']
>>> a
{}
>>> a['george'] = 2
>>> b = len([x for x in a.values() if x == 2])
>>> b
1
```

And there you have it - the pythonic way of handling the functionality you're after.

If you're trying to add functionality or limitations beyond that, you're better off starting from the dict class and extending rather than rolling your own.  Since Python is "duck-typed" there's a HUGE benefit to using the existing structure as your basis because it all falls into the same patterns.